# How do i get attributes from this xml? (PHP)

Tags: php, xml, curl

Student here, working with a school project that needs to get info from a page
with php curl. I have this code right now:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();
$url = "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml?5105e8233f9433cf70ac379d6ccc5775";
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

print("<pre>".print_r($xml,true)."</pre>");
?>
```

The output with print is this:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuYPQ.png)

How do i get the attributes such as currency and rate? Also, am i doing correctly the xml conversion? Should I chage it to json?

Edit: Output text

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [Cube] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [Cube] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [time] => 2021-03-31
                        )

                    [Cube] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency] => USD
                                            [rate] => 1.1725
                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency] => JPY
                                            [rate] => 129.91
                                        )

                                )

                            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency] => BGN
                                            [rate] => 1.9558
                                        )

                                )
                        )
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Check the php docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php, example #1. And you don't need to convert it to json just to get the data

Comment: _Small Note_ Pictures of data that is text is not helpful. Post it as text and format it, then it can be indexed AND we can easily use it to copy/paste into an answer or god forbid actually test an answer before posting it

Answer (score 0):

You are getting entangled with namespaces, unfortunately. Try declaring them and using xpath:

```
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("xxx", "http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref");
$currencies = $xml->xpath("//xxx:Cube[@currency]");
foreach($currencies as $currency) {
   $cur = $currency->xpath("./@currency")[0];
   $rate = $currency->xpath("./@rate")[0];   
   echo  $cur ." " . $rate . "\r\n" ;
   }
```

Output:

```
USD 1.1725
JPY 129.91
BGN 1.9558
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can get elements of an SimpleXML Document, as it would be in your case, like this:

```php
$elements = $xml->Cube->Cube->Cube;
```

This stems from the structure of the XML which is like this:

```xml
<Cube>
<Cube time="2021-03-31">
<Cube currency="USD" rate="1.1725"/>
[...]
</Cube>
</Cube>
```

With this (`$elements`) you can iterate over all currencys in the list like so:

```php
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
$cubes = $xml->Cube->Cube->Cube;

$rates = [];

foreach ($cubes as $key => $cube) {
  $attrs = $cube->attributes();

  # We need to do typecasting since this still returns SimpleXML elements
  # but we want the string / numeric representation.
  $name = (string) $attrs['currency'];
  $rate = (float) $attrs['rate'];
  $rates[$name] = $rate;
}

var_dump($rates);

// array(32) {
//   ["USD"]=>
//   float(1.1725)
//   ["JPY"]=>
//   float(129.91)
//   ["BGN"]=>
//   float(1.9558)
//   ["CZK"]=>
//   float(26.143)
//   ["DKK"]=>
//   float(7.4373)
//   ["GBP"]=>
//   float(0.85209)
//   ["HUF"]=>
//   float(363.27)
//   ...
// }
```

In the end, `$rates` will be a simple array with all your currencies (their names as the key) and their exchange rate. Of course, you don't need to save it to an array, within the `foreach` loop you could also write it to a database.